# Need help getting custom slideshow to autoplay

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've taken over a project that was built by someone else. The site features a custom slideshow on the home page. I've made some changes to the look/feel of the slideshow per client requests, but the last thing it needs is autoplay.

Below is the script for the slideshow. I know about `setInterval` but I'm not sure where to put it, or if the code needs to be adjusted a bit before dropping that in.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
// A little script for preloading all of the images
// It"s not necessary, but generally a good idea
$(images).each(function(index, value){
    // Ski first image since it is already loaded
    if( index != 0 ) {
        $("<img/>")[0].src = this; 
    }
});

// Feature Slider Navagitaion
$('.feature .ei-slider-nav li a').click( function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var thisLink = $(this);
    var navIndex = thisLink.parent('li').index();

    thisLink.parents('ul').children('li').removeClass('active');
    thisLink.parent('li').addClass('active');

    // Is this item already active?
    if( !$('.feature .ei-slider-title .ei-slider-title-item:eq('+navIndex+')').hasClass('active')) {

        // Fade in/out feature image
        $('.feature .ei-slider-large img').animate({opacity: 0}, 500, function() {

            // Support for non-opacity browsers
            $(this).css('visibility', 'hidden');

            // Load new feature image
            $(this).attr('src', images[navIndex]);
            $(this).attr('alt', imagesAlt[navIndex]);

            $(this).css('visibility', 'visible');

            $('.feature .ei-slider-large img').animate({opacity: 1}, 500);
        });

        // Fade in/out feature text
        $('.feature .ei-slider-title .ei-slider-title-item.active').fadeOut(500, function() {
            $(this).parent().children().removeClass('active');

            $('.feature .ei-slider-title .ei-slider-title-item:eq('+navIndex+')').addClass('active').fadeIn();
        });

        // Fade in/out feature credit
        $('.content .ei-slider-credit span.active').fadeOut(500, function() {
            $(this).parent().children().removeClass('active');

            $('.content .ei-slider-credit span:eq('+navIndex+')').addClass('active').fadeIn();
        });


    }
});

// Feature Slider Learn More
$('.feature .ei-slider-title-item-learn').click( function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    thisPrev = $(this).prev();

    if( thisPrev.css('display') == 'none') {
        thisPrev.slideDown();

        thisPrev.css('visibility', 'visible');

        thisPrev.animate({'opacity': 1}, 500, function() {

        });

        $(this).html('Hide');
    } else {

        thisPrev.animate({'opacity': 0}, 500, function() {
            thisPrev.slideUp();

            thisPrev.css('visibility', 'hidden');
        });

        $(this).html('Hide');

        $(this).html('Learn More');
    }
});
});
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would probably be a little bit easier if there were a way to keep track of the current state of the slideshow outside the context of clicking on a slide's navigation link. The first thing I would add, right above `$('.feature .ei-slider-nav li a').click( function(e) {...` would be:

```
var eiSlider = {
  currentSlideIndex: 0,
  nextSlide: null, // we will define this later
  autoPlay: null // we will define this later too
};
```

Then, inside of the function I mentioned above, as the first order of business inside of the check for whether the slide is already active, I'd add this:

```
// Set the currentSlide index on the global eiSlider tracking object
eiSlider.currentSlide = navIndex;
```

Next, you'll want to make a function to handle advancing the slideshow automatically:

```
eiSlider.nextSlide = function() {

  var currentSlideIndex = eiSlider.currentSlideIndex,
      nextSlideIndex = currentSlideIndex + 1,
      totalSlides = $('.ei-slider-large img').length;

  // If we are already at the end of the images, loop back to the beginning
  if ( nextSlideIndex < totalSlides ) {

    nextSlideIndex = 0;
  }

  // Trigger a click to move forward to the next slide
  $('.feature .ei-slider-nav li:eq(' + nextSlideIndex + ') a').trigger('click');
};
```

I've also moved the work of setting the "active" class on a given slide's nav link to happen inside of the logic around making sure the slide you clicked on wasn't already active, to make sure it doesn't get set incorrectly.

Finally, you can use setInterval (at the bottom of all of the above code) to handle the autoplay portion.

```
// Auto-advance the slides every 5 seconds. Adjust the value as necessary
eiSlider.autoPlay = window.setInterval(function(){
  eiSlider.nextSlide();
}, 5000);
```

Your final, updated code would look something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  // A little script for preloading all of the images
  // It"s not necessary, but generally a good idea
  $(images).each(function(index, value){
    // Ski first image since it is already loaded
    if( index !== 0 ) {

      $("<img/>")[0].src = this; 
    }
  });

  // Object for basic state tracking and namespacing of slideshow functions
  var eiSlider = {
    currentSlideIndex: 0,
    nextSlide: null, // we will define this later
    autoPlay: null // we will define this later too
  };

  // Feature Slider Navagitaion
  $('.feature .ei-slider-nav li a').click( function(e) {

    e.preventDefault();

    var thisLink = $(this),
        navIndex = thisLink.parent('li').index();

      // Is this item already active?
      if( !$('.feature .ei-slider-title .ei-slider-title-item:eq('+navIndex+')').hasClass('active')) {

        thisLink.closest('li').siblings().removeClass('active');
        thisLink.closest('li').addClass('active');

        // Set the currentSlide index on the global eiSlider tracking object
        eiSlider.currentSlideIndex = navIndex;

        // Fade in/out feature image
        $('.feature .ei-slider-large img').animate({opacity: 0}, 500, function() {

          // Support for non-opacity browsers
          $(this).css('visibility', 'hidden');

          // Load new feature image
          $(this).attr('src', images[navIndex]);
          $(this).attr('alt', imagesAlt[navIndex]);
          $(this).css('visibility', 'visible');
          $('.feature .ei-slider-large img').animate({opacity: 1}, 500);
        });

        // Fade in/out feature text
        $('.feature .ei-slider-title .ei-slider-title-item.active').fadeOut(500, function() {

          $(this).parent().children().removeClass('active');
          $('.feature .ei-slider-title .ei-slider-title-item:eq('+navIndex+')').addClass('active').fadeIn();
        });

        // Fade in/out feature credit
        $('.content .ei-slider-credit span.active').fadeOut(500, function() {

          $(this).parent().children().removeClass('active');
          $('.content .ei-slider-credit span:eq('+navIndex+')').addClass('active').fadeIn();
        });
      }
  });

  // Feature Slider Learn More
  $('.feature .ei-slider-title-item-learn').click( function(e) {

    e.preventDefault();
    thisPrev = $(this).prev();

    if ( thisPrev.css('display') === 'none') {

      thisPrev.slideDown();
      thisPrev.css('visibility', 'visible');
      thisPrev.animate({'opacity': 1}, 500, function() {});

      $(this).html('Hide');

    } else {

      thisPrev.animate({'opacity': 0}, 500, function() {
        thisPrev.slideUp();
        thisPrev.css('visibility', 'hidden');
      });

      $(this).html('Hide');
      $(this).html('Learn More');
    }
  });

  // Function to handle slide advancement
  eiSlider.nextSlide = function() {

    var currentSlideIndex = eiSlider.currentSlideIndex,
        nextSlideIndex = currentSlideIndex + 1,
        totalSlides = $('.ei-slider-large img').length;

    // If we are already at the end of the images, loop back to the beginning
    if ( currentSlideIndex < (totalSlides - 1) ) {

      nextSlideIndex = 0;
    }

    // Trigger a click to move forward to the next slide
    $('.feature .ei-slider-nav li:eq(' + nextSlideIndex + ') a').trigger('click');
  };

  // Auto-advance the slides every 5 seconds. Adjust the value as necessary
  eiSlider.autoPlay = window.setInterval(function(){
    eiSlider.nextSlide();
  }, 5000);

});
```

Bear in mind this answer makes a few assumptions, the main one being that the `eiSldier` namespace is available; if it's not, just use a different namespace than the one I provided, OR add these three new items to the existing namespace so it doesn't get overwritten. The only change in that case would not be defining `eiSlider` as an object with three properties, but instead defining simply `eiSlider.currentSlide = 0`, and then proceeding to define the other two functions the way they already are defined later on in the example.

If the `eiSlider` namespace already exists, it's entirely possible that `currentSlide` or some equivalent property exists on it already, so you could take advantage of that if it does, rather than making a duplicate (or worse, overriding it in a way that could cause errors in the rest of its functionality).

One thing I should note that the code above doesn't currently do is stop/clear the autoplay out when you manually click on a slide's navigation link. That's a pretty important usability issue that will need to get cleaned up. You can accomplish this by using `clearInterval(eiSlider.autoPlay)`, but to make that really work correctly, you'd need to separate out the code that handles slide advancement from the actual click event.

Check out this slightly modified JS Bin that shows the auto-advance working as intended, plus the changes I mentioned above with clearInterval:

http://jsbin.com/gumaqefere/1/edit?html,js,console,output

Comment: Thanks Evan. I looked through it and applied the changes but it doesn't work. eiSlider is available as far as I can tell, but I changed it just in case and still nothing. No errors in the console either. The slider still works as before, it's just the additional auto play code that doesn't work. Total noob here. :)

Comment: Hey Angie— there were a few errors in the original code. I've fixed those and made some additional enhancements. Autoplay should be working now, and if you check out the JS Bin I link to, you can see how to disable autoplay once the user clicks on a slide's navigation link as well.